# Finding a rare attribute

Tags: java, xml, nodes, element, w3c

I am trying to read in data from an XML file with dbFactory, and am struggling with finding an attribute that is not always there ("image") that can be seen in step5 and then not in step6 from the data below:

here is some data from the file

```
    <screen>
            <screenID>step_5</screenID>
            <video>/video/Task 5 - Open Word.mp4</video>
            <vid_caption>Task 5 - Open Word</vid_caption>
            <image>/shared_images/word_icon.png</image>
        </screen>
        <screen>
            <screenID>step_6</screenID>
            <video>/video/Task 6 - How to open MS Word.mp4</video>
            <vid_caption>Task 6 - How to open MS Word</vid_caption>
        </screen>
```

I have tried with streams and this is my last, I feel that I am missing something simple, below is the program that I have created for it

```
            //imports for XML readers
    import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
    import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
    import org.w3c.dom.Document;
    import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
    import org.w3c.dom.Node;
    import org.w3c.dom.Element;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    public class ReadXML 
    {

        public static void main(String args[]) 
        {
           //try to read in the file
           try 
           {
     //create the file to read in
   //File XmlFile = new File("Documents\\University\\2017\\Courses\\Second Semester\\CSC3003S\\Capstone\\Program\\Capstone-master\\elearnerselfstudy.xml");

  File XmlFile = new File("elearnerselfstudy.txt");
  //Defines a factory API that enables applications to obtain a parser that produces DOM object trees from XML documents.
  DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
   DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
   Document document = dBuilder.parse(XmlFile);

  //need to normalize - read the stack overflow
   document.getDocumentElement().normalize();

  //print out root for testing purposes
   System.out.println("The root element is :" + document.getDocumentElement().getNodeName() + "\n");

  //list of lessons - it is reading the elements into the list fine
   NodeList nLessonList = document.getElementsByTagName("lesson");
  System.out.println("I have the lesson list ready");
  System.out.println("The length of the lessonList is: " + nLessonList.getLength()+"\n");

  //list for the screens - it is reading the elements into the list fine, the error is somewhere else
  NodeList nScreenList = document.getElementsByTagName("screen");
  System.out.println("I have the screen list ready");
  System.out.println("The length of the screenList is: " + nScreenList.getLength()+ "\n");

  //lesson list iteration
   for (int temp = 0; temp < nLessonList.getLength(); temp++) 
  {
       Node nNode = nLessonList.item(temp);
       System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getNodeName());

       if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) 
     {
        //System.out.println("Are we even insdie the if bro - we definitely penetrate the if");
        //System.out.println("Still not a good enough reason to use the word penetrate" + "\n");

           Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

        //System.out.println("Lesson : " + eElement.getAttribute("lesson"));
        System.out.println("Lesson : " + eElement.getAttribute("lesson_title"));
        System.out.println("Lesson ID : " + eElement.getAttribute("lesson_id"));
        System.out.println("Lesson Type : " + eElement.getAttribute("lesson_type"));



       }//end if 
   }//end for loop through tree

  //screen list iteration
  for (int temp = 0; temp < nScreenList.getLength(); temp++) 
  {
       Node nNode2 = nScreenList.item(temp);
       System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode2.getNodeName());

       if (nNode2.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) 
     {            
           Element eElement = (Element) nNode2;

        //return elements
        //System.out.println("Screen : " + eElement.getAttribute("screen"));
        System.out.println("ScreenId is  : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("screenID").item(0).getTextContent());
        System.out.println("Video is  : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("video").item(0).getTextContent());
        System.out.println("Video Caption is  : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("vid_caption").item(0).getTextContent());

        if (eElement.getAttributeNode("image")!=null)//(eElement.hasAttribute("image")==true)
        {

           System.out.println("Image is  : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("image").item(0).getTextContent());
        }


     }//end if 
  }//end for list iteration
}//end try

 //catch
 catch (Exception e) 
{
   e.printStackTrace();
}//end catch
    }//end main
    }//end class
```

Comment: According to your XML markup, `image` is an element, not an attribute.

Answer (score 0):

```
//get the image path if it is there
if (eElement.getElementsByTagName("image").item(0)!=null)
{
    System.out.println("Image path is  : " +eElement.getElementsByTagName("image").item(0).getTextContent());
}
```